# Dry Lining Wall - Should I stagger the joints in this project?

Tags: drywall

I have 5 sheets of 8' x 4' sheet rock laminated insulation to affix inside a bedroom - the wall to which I am affixing is a cavity brick wall built in the 1990's. The internal height is just under 8'. The easiest thing for me to do would be to place the sheets vertically and not stagger any joints.

Is there any benefit or need to start making things more difficult and placing the sheets horizontally and staggering the joints?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of staggered joints, is to provide  additional support and rigidity, to the the framing members below - as well as make it easier to keep a uniform surface, over any uneven framing.

Your wall should be fine, with all sheets hung vertical, on appropriately spaced furring strips.

Comment: This is the right answer.  When working with 8ft drywall on a wall longer than 8-ft, I hang them vertically.  This avoids taping non-tapered joints.   Where the joints are I place horizontal blocking at about 16-in intervals to keep the joints aligned.